# How do I add the first 2 letters of every line in a file to a list using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, list

I have a file ($ScriptName). I want the first 2 charactors of every line to be in a list (Starters). I am using a bash script.

How would I do this?

I have declared my array like this:

```
array=() #Empty array
```

Using guidence from this: https://opensource.com/article/18/5/you-dont-know-bash-intro-bash-arrays

I am using manjaro 19 and the latest kernel.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have looked for some commands however had no look with finding any. There is no error I just do not know any of the commands to do this.

Comment: Consider looking at the command `cut` for hints. You could also use the bash `mapfile` command (`help mapfile`) to read data in directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first two *characters* from each line, you can use

```
cut -c1,2 "$ScriptName"
```

`-c1,2` means "output characters in positions 1 and 2"

I'm not sure what you mean by a "list". If you just want to create a file with the results, use redirection:

```
cut -c1,2 "$ScriptName" > Starters
```

If you want to populate an array, just use

```
while IFS= read -r starter ; do Starters+=("$starter") ; done < <(cut -c1,2 "$ScriptName")
```

Moreover, if you're interested in *letters* rather than characters, you can use sed to remove non-letters from each line and then use the solution shown above.

```
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]//g' "$ScriptName" | cut -c1,2
```

Comment: I mean a array that only has one row ie. (1 2 4 6 3 5 7).

Comment: I am just interested in the charactors,

Comment: `=+` and `+=` are not equivalent. Also, no spaces around assignment operators in bash.

Comment: Also, study `man bash` or a similar resource on what parentheses mean. You can't just randomly type characters and expect the shell to guess what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - lots of detail and really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean (except for a missing initialization of `ScriptName`) pure Bash code:

```
Starters=()
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    Starters+=( "${line:0:2}" )
done < "$ScriptName"
```

- See [Arrays [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays) for information about using arrays in Bash.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
  for information about reading files line-by-line in Bash.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) (particularly the bit about "range notation") for an explanation of `${line:0:2}"`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`mapfile`](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) bash built-in command combined with `cut` makes it simple:

```
cut -c1,2 "$ScriptName" | mapfile Starters
```